# IOS UIWebview alternative - Does it have a webkit browser we can use as a webview different than Safari?

Tags: webview, uiwebview, safari, webkit

I'm looking for an alternative for safari webview I could use like a UIWebview and to communicate with javascript of his webview.

Is it possible? Is Apple tolerant of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question touches on something deeply fundamental in Apple's entire iOS strategy:

At least not yet. Even Google had to rely on embedding the standard (albeit tweaked) `UIWebView` to implement Chrome for iOS. We can expect Apple to be very reluctant to allow this since allowing other web renderers (possibly even with alternative JS implementations, e.g. V8) kind of breaks Apple's monopoly on control of the development environment for iOS. Allowing an alternative would essentially mean allowing an alternative runtime getting a foothold on the platform.

Although me personally, I think they will have a hard time in the long run to keep this level of purity.

Comment: Yes they will have a harde time.The main problem I have is that Safari mobile (mainly in a uiwebview) block for 4 days the "autoplay" and the "basic play" of a youtube iframe without real user interaction.I cannot find a solution... This alternative would be one.

Answer (score 1):

Although still inspired by Safari, starting from iOS8 there is [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/), a WebKit-based component that provides more powerful, higher-performance APIs than the older UIWebView.